# Reading negative numbers with getch()

Tags: c

So I'm working through the C programming language book. And working through the calculator questions. It asked to add support for negative numbers; which I did but I found a weird behaviour I can't explain.

```
int getop(char s[])
{
    int i = 0, c, next;
    /* Skip whitespace */
    while((s[0] = c = getch()) == ' ' || c == '\t')
        ;
    s[1] = '\0';    
    /* Not a number but may contain a unary minus. */
    if(!isdigit(c) && c != '.' && c != '-')
        return c;
    if(c == '-')
    {
        next = getch();
        if(!isdigit(next) && next != '.')
           return c;
        c = next;
    }
    else
        c = getch();    

    while(isdigit(s[++i] = c)) //HERE
            c = getch();
    if(c == '.')                     /* Collect fraction part. */
        while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
                        ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Works for positive numbers and negative numbers

```
int getop(char s[])
{
    ...

    while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch())) //HERE
            ;
    if(c == '.')                     /* Collect fraction part. */
        while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
                        ;
    s[i] = '\0';
    if(c != EOF)
        ungetch(c);
    return NUMBER;
}
```

Works ONLY for positive numbers.

Why!?

getch()

```
char buf[BUFSIZE]; /* buffer for ungetch */
int bufp = 0; /* next free position in buf */    
int getch(void) /* get a (possibly pushed-back) character */    {
    return (bufp > 0) ? buf[--bufp] : getchar();
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, I get it, ill accept answer when I can.

Comment: Your second version doesn't work for any sort of number -- it fails to store the first digit into `s`.

Comment: Your getch provides `BUFSIZE` bytes of push-back, when you only need one. Why not just use getchar() and ungetc(c, stdin)? And, as I mentioned below, isdigit(s[...]) results in undefined behavior if you read a non-ASCII character. The GNU libc guards against this and won't do an undefined access, but some other C libraries will. It's best to write the code so you call isdigit(c), not isdigit(s[i]), but if you must do the latter, you should cast it to unsigned char.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while(isdigit(s[++i] = c))
    c = getch();
```

and

```
while(isdigit(s[++i] = c = getch()))
    ;
```

have different behavior. The latter reads once before entering the loop and checks if the value read is a digit, while the former checks if the previously read value was a digit.

Comment: This code has undefined behavior if characters with values larger than can fit in a `signed char` are read. Values of type `char` (such as `s[...]`) should be cast to `(unsigned char)` before passing them to `is...` or `to...`.